# WSO2 - Data Service - GZIP - Data compression - JSON

Tags: wso2, gzip, wso2-data-services-server, http-compression

I have a DataService (behind a managed API) that have to receive a JSON gziped (as it is a large dataset).

Micro integrator:  WSO2MI-4.2.0
API Manager  :  WSO2AM-4.2.0
Identity MGT:   WSO2IS-6.0.0

But I receive this error message:

```
<faultstring>I/O  Exception occured while building the data service request</faultstring>


[2023-05-22 12:49:56,791] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} - Error processing POST request for : /services/dsfenicio_testing/insertarLogImportacion_test org.apache.axis2.AxisFault$
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.handlers.IntegratorStatefulHandler.invoke(IntegratorStatefulHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:379)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:438)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:458)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:221)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:127)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:94)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.handlers.IntegratorStatefulHandler.invoke(IntegratorStatefulHandler.java:90)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:174)
        ... 14 more

Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:625)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:997)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:754)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2000)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidInitial(UTF8Reader.java:303)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:189)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:87)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:57)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:991)
        ... 26 more

[2023-05-22 12:49:56,791]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} - Server encountered an error, the request message will be consumed and discarded, , CLIENT_ADDRESS = /192.168.134.81$
```

any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete error trace?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just added the error trace. Pls advise. Daniel

Comment: What is the content type (Content-Type header value) of the message?

Comment: is : application/gzip  .  pls advise. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `deploymet.toml`

```yaml
[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"
content_type = "application/gzip"

[[custom_message_formatters]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"
content_type = "application/gzip"
```

Comment: Just did it, but Micro-integrator didn't load. 
'Error: [2023-05-23 13:50:50,204] FATAL {org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.internal.CoreServerInitializer} - WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuil$'

Comment: @DanielCapone Sorry I had a typo in the answer. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!.  it seems that now it worked.. but I had this error. any clue?
            <faultcode>axis2ns36:INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR</faultcode>
            <faultstring>DS Fault Message: Error in DS non result invoke.
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:psitio
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR

Comment: @DanielCapone ok now we have to take a step back. What is your use case? Why do you use a content type like `application/gzip` if you want to call DSS. This content type indicates the content is a binary compresed content.

Comment: I have a DSS invoked by an API that receives a json with records to be inserted. As it is a large dataset, I use a json.gzip file to do a batch request. As the 1st error was "Exception occured while building the data service request" raised by the MI,  I set to OFF the API and started doing troubleshooting over the DSS. I suppouse that when the DSS works fine with the compressed file,  the API will work as well.  Pls let me know if this information helps you. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @DanielCapone are you getting a file? Or do you get a JSON body with the content encoding gzip? DSS will only understand XML or JSON.

Comment: I have a file called records.json  that was gzipped to records.json.gz.  I tried to attach the the body as  "binary"  and also selecting (in postman) form-data and attched it as file key. I guess I'm doing something really wrong.... :(

Comment: just to clarify, the DSS goal is to insert data in the DB, based on a json

Comment: I tried also with another DSS and json structure and received the same error.

Comment: This error simply indicates that it cannot find the Input parameters you have maped in your resource. So in both cases it has the same cause. First case it can't find them because it's binary data, in the second case probably your mappings are off.

Comment: Hi @ycr,  I'm still working on this issue. The main question I have is :  Does a dataservice running on Micro-integrator (4.2.0) supports a gziped json? (file.json.gzip)?  Because below curl instruction to do a batch req (batch insert in a database) results in error:
 curl -X POST http://localhost:8290/services/dsfenicio_testing/inserta_en_daniel_batch_req" -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept-encoding:gzip " --data-binary "@dd.json.gz"

ERROR:  {"Fault":{"faultcode":"soapenv:Server","faultstring":"javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unexpected end of json stream","detail":""}

Comment: @DanielCapone If your content encoding is GZIP you need to set the header `-H "Content-Encoding: gzip"`

Comment: thanks so much. it worked! .  really apprecitated.